# How do I convert this specific time into the one here?

Tags: php, sql, date, time, converters

I am scraping data from a website which uses this time format:

Saturday, February 7, 2015 and in another place they mention the hour e.g. 12:45.

I've managed to get them together in a string as follows:
Saturday, February 7, 2015 12:45

But the time data in my SQL table is as follows:
2015-01-13 09:49:43.000000

I am using strtotime to insert the data into the database. My code looks as follows:

```
$dateTime=$date.$time.'';
```

When I print $dateTime I get "Saturday, February 7, 2015 17:30". And when I put that manually in strtotime it works great. However, if I send $dateTime to strtotime it fails and gives default 1970 time. I've double checked that its type is string.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/es/function.date.php

Comment: several variations of strtotime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Like using PHP's `DateTime` class, here's an example.

```
$newdate = new DateTime($yourdate);
$date = $newdate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE table SET column = ? WHERE row = ?")
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $date, $row);
$stmt->execute();
```

**EDIT :**
So you're not getting a correctly formatted date from the scraped site, it's HTML. I would recommend handling this with JQuery.

Here's what you've got:

```
<th colspan="3" class="comp-date"> Saturday, February 7, 2015</th><td class="status"> 17:30</td>
```

We can get the information needed with the class names, the below code will need to go into a PHP file.

```
<?php
    $scrapedDate = ....;
?>
<html>
<head>
//add JQuery to the <head> section//
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
    $scraped = '<?= $scrapedDate ?>'; //get data from PHP//
    $scrapedDate = $($scraped).closest('.comp-date').text().trim();
    $scrapedTime = $($scraped).closest('.status').text();
    $dateTime = $scrapedDate+$scrapedTime;

    alert($dateTime);
    return false;
});
</script>
</head>
```

I tested this and it works, but, after doing this you need to get it back into PHP which you can use AJAX to do.

Comment: I have date in this format as $dateTime:
Saturday, February 7, 2015 17:30

The following does not work: 
    $dateTimeSQL=Date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime($dateTime));
it prints
    1970-01-01 01:00:00

However, if I do this:
    Date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime('Saturday, February 7, 2015 17:30'));

It displays correctly as 
   2015-02-07 05:30:00

What could be wrong?

Comment: Have you tried my answer? Formatting should be correct with it.

Comment: It seems that my date variable is getting hidden html from the source website since it's being scrapped. Thanks to an error from your solution I discoverd this. See the error:
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (&lt;th colspan=&quot;3&quot; class=&quot;comp-date&quot;&gt; Saturday, February 7, 2015&lt;/th&gt;&lt;td class=&quot;status&quot;&gt; 17:30&lt;/td&gt;) 

How do I remove the HTML and leave the date only in my variable? And why when I echo it only the date gets printed? giving the idea that it's a clean date?

Answer (score 0):

```
Date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime($datestring));
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you contstucting your $dateTime string? Could you post code? Looks like your halfway to the answer

Something like:
    $dateTime = $day.",".$month.",".$year;

Comment: $dateTime=$date.$time.''; 

When I print $dateTime I get "Saturday, February 7, 2015 17:30". And when I put that manually in strtotime it works. However if I send $dateTime to strtotime it fails and gives default 1970 time.